# Any way to disable f12 developer tools?

Tags: internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

Any way of disabling the ability to press f12 and have the dev window pop up?  Running IE10 and IE11.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/152554-internet-explorer-f12-developer-tools-enable-disable.html) here is a program that will allow you to disable the developer tools.